# How to search a network share?

Tags: nautilus, ssh, files, samba, search

Usually when I want to find a particular file on my local machine, I'll open up a terminal and do `find . -name "*blah*"` from the directory which I want to search within.  Now I want to search from a network share, which I can access in nautilus by browsing to `smb://192.168.1.x/blah/` ... or by `ssh://192.168.1.x/blah/` .. but how can I open a terminal at this location and/or search for files there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mount a network share in Nautilus in the **Connect to Server** window, the share is mounted in `/home/$USER/.gvfs`. So, if your username is bob, and you have mounted the network share **Shared Docs** on the computer Windows, it would be mounted under `/home/bob/.gvfs/Shared Docs on Windows`.

Comment: Note though that if you're in the terminal accessing this, spaces in directory names need to be escaped (like this: `/home/iamgod/The\ Ending`)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. You can also put the path in quotes (like this: `"/home/iamgod/The Ending"`)

Comment: Some programs don't parse that right, if you're using a program to edit files via full-paths, hence why i mentioned escaping.